# How to get dialogue to change upon clicking on an image?

Tags: javascript, onclick, counter, dreamweaver, var

I'm trying to create a game with dialogue, and I want my text to change as the player clicks on a `next` image to progress the story.

For example:

```
Page loads - "Hi, I'm Joe."

Clicks sliced Image once - "Nice to meet you."

Clicks 2nd time - "How are you?"
```

I have tried `onClick` but that only allows me to change it once, I've tried using var counter as well but to no avail, it overrides my previous commands, which part of this am I doing wrong here?

```js
var clicks = 0;

function changeText() {
  {
    clicks = 1;
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Ughh... my head... What     
    happened...?";
  }
}

function changeText() {
  {
    clicks = 2;
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Testing 1 2 3";
  }
}

function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<img onClick="changeText(); audio.play()" value=Change Text src="images/awaken/images/awaken_03.jpg" alt="" width="164" height="77" id="clicks" />
<p id="text">Where... am I...?</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! First you have 2 function named `changeText()`. second you have extra `{}` in same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all - your changeText() system is flawed - you're overwriting the same function multiple times *at the same time*, so the only one of those that will ever get called is the last one you declare. JavaScript doesn't wait until a function gets called to continue with the program.
The audio.play() also won't work - but I'm assuming that's a work in progress.
I changed your code so that instead of setting count to a specific value, it increments every time the function gets called, and it updates the text to the correct value in an array. Here's the updated changeText function:

```
var count = 0;
var text = [
"Where... am I...?", /* note that this will never get called, it's simply here for filling up the array*/
"This is the first text!",
"And this is the second!"
]
var changeText = function() {
   count++;
   document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text[count];
}
```

In the future, you'll probably also want to check `if(text[count] != 'undefined')`, and if so write something like "Bye!" instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot! This worked! However, is there a way to disable the button by the time I reach the last text instead of having it say "undefined"? I'm thinking it's something to do with the if(text[count]... but I'm completely new to javascript and have no clue how that works, would be great if you could explain it a bit further!

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues in your code

1. Multiple function declaration of `changeText()`
2. Extra `{}` in `changeText()`
3. You are not updating value of `clicks`.
4. In your html, you have written `audo.play()` but no `audio` object is available. It should be `play()`. I have called `play()` function in `changeText()` function. This keeps HTML clean.

Following is updated code:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function changeText() {
    var text = "" 
    clicks++;
    switch(clicks){
        case 1: text = "Ughh... my head... What happened...?";
          break;
        case 2: text = "Testing 1 2 3";
          break;
    }
    
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
  
  play();
}

function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<img onClick="changeText()" value=Change Text src="images/awaken/images/awaken_03.jpg" alt="" width="164" height="77" id="clicks" />
<p id="text">Where... am I...?</p>
```